# PHP while() wrapping items

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, while-loop

I have this html code:

```
<div class="row elem2">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="row elem4">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="row elem3">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

and I am looking for a way to implement it in my php while (wordpress).
The while is as

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   echo '<div class="item"></div>';
endwhile;
```

I've tried a lot of stuff, but none have worked. I need to divide every 2 items and put them in a wrap `<div class="row elem2">` after that the next 4 items in `<div class="row elem4">` and after that the next 3 items in `<div class="row elem3">`

I did a lot of searching, but I am not even sure what to search for.

Comment: How about a counter you increase in each iteration of your loop? You check for the 2nd, 6th and 9th element. As soon as it hits 9, you set it back to 0. Then you can easily insert the `<div class="row elemX">` and `</div>`. Try to implement it and show us what you got in case you don't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little crude but here's one solution

```
$i = 0; // Number of items made so far in the row
$mode = 0; // Current row type enumerated by $elem
$elem = array(2,4,3); // Enumeration of the desired row sizes
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // Make a new row when there's no items yet
    if ($i == 0) echo '<div class="row elem'. $elem[$mode] .'">';
    echo '<div class="item"></div>';
    $i++;
    // Once the items in the current row has reached the row's maximum size
    if ($i % $elem[$mode] == 0):
        echo '</div>'; 
        $i = 0; // Reset items made for the row back to 0
        $mode = ($mode + 1) % 3; // Increment mode and wrap if necessary
    endif;
endwhile;
if ($i > 0) echo '</div>'; // Finish the last row if it wasn't finished
```

This is what the modulos was built for!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!
I almost got it a lot more spaghetti-like code, but still got to think how to fix: if the last "elem2", "elem3", "elem4" have respectively 1,2 or 3 elements :(

Comment: I was thinking of using `next()` to move through the `$elem` var but I wasn't sure if it would wrap back to the first element once the end was reached. If this answer works for you, please mark it off as accepted :)